# How to speed up this Dart micro-benchmark?

Tags: dart, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I'm benchmarking this function in Dart Editor:

```dart
e28({N: 1000}) {   
  int diagNumber = 1;         
  int sum        = diagNumber;          

  for (int width = 2; width <= N; width += 2)  
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {     
      diagNumber += width;        
      sum        += diagNumber;     
    }

  return sum;
}
```

I created command line application and unchecked `Run in checked mode`. Is there anything else I can do to make it run faster? I noticed that `Process properties` dialog shows `--debug` option in command line. What is the way to remove debug option? Is there a release or optimize option?

Small, algorithm preserving modifications of code are allowed (e.g. more concise notation),  but making it much more verbose (e.g. loop unrolling) is not. Given these constraints, can you write a faster version of `e28()`?

My current results on Xubuntu 13.04 64-bit Core i5 3450S 2.8GHz are about 10x slower than the same code in C++ or D compiled with LLVM. The upside is that it beats Scala, Julia, F# and of course Python, but I expected somewhat faster Dart performance.

Here is the way it is timed:

```dart
void main() {
  final N         = 100000;
  var   timer     = new Stopwatch()..start();
  var   resultMin = e28();
  var   timeMin   = timer.elapsedMicroseconds;

  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    var t0    = timer.elapsedMicroseconds;
    var r     = e28();
    var t1    = timer.elapsedMicroseconds;
    timeMin   = min(timeMin, t1-t0);
    resultMin = min(resultMin, r);
  }

  print(timeMin);
  print(resultMin);
}
```

BTW, when I use the official benchmark harness, I'm getting 10x longer run times. I suspect that `benchmark_harness.dart` doesn't report minimum time, but median time perhaps. **[EDIT]** Never mind 10x issue in `benchmark_harness.dart`: it is by design.

Comment: Is N = 1000 the actual number you are testing against?

Comment: @PixelElephant Yes, I'll add `main()` listing to my question in a moment.

Comment: you **might** *maybe* type the e28 function as returning int.  and resultMin as int also. And use types everywhere in fact, this way you  are sure the compiler did its best. Strange you mention both 1000 and 10000 with same name (N).

Comment: @GameAlchemist I tried specifying `int` type, but it doesn't change the run time. I don't think Dart's JIT has a problem to infer return type of `e28()`. `N` is used in two different scopes, so the semantics is fine, but it may be somewhat confusing.